# How to load C library functions into assembly, and use assembly library functions in another C or assembly project

Tags: c, macos, assembly, x86-64, nasm

Currently I am building a `foo.h` and `foo.c` with:

```
$ clang -I . -dynamiclib \
  -undefined dynamic_lookup \
  -o foo.dylib foo.c
```

I am able to use this in other C libraries like this:

```
clang -I . -dynamiclib \
  -undefined dynamic_lookup \
  -o bar.dylib bar.c foo.dylib
```

I would like to use this library in an assembly project.

```
$ nasm -f macho64 test.asm \
  && ld -e start -macosx_version_min 10.13.0 -static -o test test.o foo.dylib
$ ./test
ld: warning: foo.dylib, ignoring unexpected dylib file
```

Wondering how I link together the C -> asm system to get the C functions working in asm. Then I would like to go further and use that compiled asm to use in either a C or asm project, so wondering how to do that.

When using the assembly in C, I would like for you to basically get functions and import `#include "myassembly.h"` or something like that, so it feels like a real library. Then you have a function like `myfunc` which is defined in assembly, but you can use it in c as `myfunc(1, 2, 3);` sort of thing.

If I change it from static to dynamic linking with the `-lSystem` flag (and removing `-static`), I get this:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: foo.dylib
  Referenced from: ./test
  Reason: image not found
make: *** [...] Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're specifying `-static` which means:

> ```
>  -static     Produces a mach-o file that does not use the dyld.  Only used
>              building the kernel.
> ```

`dyld` is the dynamic loader. If you're not using the dynamic loader, you can't use dynamic libraries.

---

Update for edited question:

When a dylib is created, it gets an "install name". When an executable is linked to that dylib, the executable stores the install name of the dylib in its reference to it. (Note, it does **not** store the link-time path of the dylib file it linked against.) When the executable is loaded, the dynamic loader looks for the dylib using the install name it recorded, by default.

You can specify the install name using the `-install_name <name>` option to the linker. It could be the absolute path to where you expect the library to be installed (e.g. /usr/local/lib/foo.dylib), if you expect it to be installed in a fixed location. Often, though, that's not useful. You want a more flexible means for the dynamic loader to find the dylib.

The dynamic loader understands certain special path prefixes on install names to support such flexibility. See the `dyld(1)` man page. For example, if you specify an install name of `@executable_path/foo.dylib` then, at load time, the loader will look next to the executable for the library.

You can see the install name of a dylib by using `otool -D foo.dylib`. Your dylib may not have an install name, in which case its effective install name is just its file name with no path.

If the loader doesn't find the library by using its install name, it has a search strategy. By default, it looks in ~/lib:/usr/local/lib:/lib:/usr/lib. You can use some environment variables to alter the search strategy. For example, you can set `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` to a colon-delimited list of directories to search, instead. These environment variables are also listed in the `dyld(1)` man page.

Comment: Updated the question, I get "image not found" if I try dynamic linking.

Comment: I don't have `dyld` on my mac.

Comment: Not sure what to make of your comment in light of you accepting the answer, but: yes, you have `dyld` on your Mac. It's essential for its function. Nothing would work without it. Are you just referring to the man page?